# Extend boot camp (mac) partition

Tags: windows-7, macos, multi-boot, boot-camp

I have windows on boot camp installed, but I don't have enough hard drive space so i want to increase it. Is there any safe way to do this whitout reinstalling the whole boot camp + windows stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php) to adjust the partition size.  I boot from an external drive that has OS X and iPart on it, then adjust the partition as I need to.  I believe you'll have to decrypt the partition/s first (if they are encrypted) then you can run iPart.